# Exclude files in a shell script that has a certain pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I need to create a shell script that create thumbnails of files in a certain directory, but exclude those that already is created. 
The original files is named using a five digit number .jpg. Eg. *13993.jpg*. Th thumbnails is named *13993_thumb.jpg*. 
The code below is what i have started with bu I am not able to find the matching pattern...
Any suggestions?

```sh
 #!/bin/bash
 for i in *.jpg
 do
 echo "Prcoessing image $i ..."
 [[ $i == "0-9_thumb.jpg"* ]]  && continue
 # /usr/bin/convert -thumbnail 200 $i thumb.$i
 done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use the power of utils and pipes:

```
$ ls *.jpg
11223.jpg  12345_thumb.jpg  42424.jpg  99999_thumb.jpg
$ ls *.jpg | grep -v '^[0-9]\{5\}_thumb\.jpg' | while read f; do echo convert $f ... ; done
convert 11223.jpg ...
convert 42424.jpg ...
```

Regular expression in your case:

```sh
[[ "12345_thumb.jpg" =~ ^[0-9]{5}_thumb\.jpg$ ]]
```

Comment: Whatever you do **never parse output of ls** to achieve something simple like this.

Comment: @anubhava, read the question carefully: "The original files is named using a five digit number .jpg. Eg. 13993.jpg."

Comment: That has nothing to do with the concern of **parsing** output of `ls`. Do some research on why is a risky solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct glob pattern.You need to use:

```
[[ "$i" == [0-9]*"_thumb.jpg" ]] && continue
```

1. Character class `[0-9]*` will match 1 or more digits
2. Glob pattern should not be in the quotes only literal text needs to be in quotes

Comment: May I know the reason os un-accepting the answer? Just to let you know other answer can cause glaring problems since it is parsing output of `ls` (files with space or new lines will break it right away). Moreover it is using multiple pipes to achieve something which can be done in much simpler way.

Comment: In a more complex tasks, `grep` allows to use a more powerful Perl regexps, while Bash has only globbing patterns and extended regular expressions.

Comment: And using the idiom listed in the question looks like a sort of Bash'ism.

Comment: But for simple cases (like the one asked by the author) using `for` + `continue` is no problem at all :)

Comment: I answers on glob pattern because question is trying to do same. There is no doubt regex is more powerful but even **that can be done in pure BASH**. For this case glob pattern `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"_thumb.jpg"` will also work.